# How to avoid multiple times loading of librxtxSerial.so in Java

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, rxtx

I have the following code used by multiple packages:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni -cp
                    /usr/share/java/RXTXcomm.jar</argLine>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

so I'm getting `already loadded in another classloader` on Ubuntu 14.04. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If possible ssupply the `-Djava.library.path` during the execution, that should be simplest if you can access the process.

Comment: @11thdimension: Can you please tell me how to supply during the execution?

Comment: I mean during the execution, if it's an executable then `java -jar jarfile -Djava.library.path "/path"`, if it's a web application like then change the `java_opts` for the container like tomcat.